# React Tree Entity Routing

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a tree entity which in my case is a category and every category can have child categories. I don't know how many layers the tree has.

I have a component that fetches a category's child categories and I want to use it for every layer.

First of all what is the best practice to generate routes for this scenario?
With one level it's easy: `/categories/:id` but how do I continue from there? `/categories/:firstLevelId/:secondLevelId/...`?

Note that an infinite amount of layers can be possible.

Second, how can I generate routes like that in ReactJS?
To start off I already have `/categories/:id` but I don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the recursive routes example here:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths